# IQ test question: 3x3 grid with 3 possible colors

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

Faced with this question during job interview and wondering what is the solution.

[image: progressive-matrix]

Comment: the answer is a. :)

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate more on why a? :)

Comment: Is solving this puzzle part of your interview? Did you ask after the interview was finished, or did you ask us midway? What "rights" does the puzzle create reserve, per the footer? Do they allow you to post the question elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

for blues, you will take

> sum of blues with their right locations, two blues + one blue becomes three blues with right locations.

for other colors,

> you will take the different resulting as green. for first one two green one red results 1 green, for the other one three green two red becomes one green and so on.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> First piece

Because

> Blue squares in the last row are added
>  Red squares in the central row delete the greens ones

But

> I'm not sure about the green squares in the center row

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this is the solution.